# How can I match 2 or 3 colons using sed?

Tags: regex, sed, matching, regex-group

I'm playing around with regex groups and got stuck on something that was bothering me. Given the following:

```
TestEko:::Test
TestEko::Test
```

I can't manage to match the groups of colons. I've tried the following:

```
\(::\|:::\)  # only matches ::
\(:\{2,3\}\) # only matches ::
\(::\+\)     # only matches ::
```

So, how can I match both `:::` on the first line and `::` in the second line?

Comment: `\(::|:::\)` # should work.  (Don't escape the "or" (`|`) operator). Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every tool has a slightly different way of handling regular expression.  And even sed has different ways, because there are multiple implementations of sed.

If you're in Linux, you're probably running GNU sed, which will do what you want without much extra effort:

```
$ printf 'one::two\nthree:::four\n' | sed 's/:::\?/_/'
one_two
three_Four
```

In FreeBSD, however, you're using BSD sed, which does not work the same way as GNU.  In FreeBSD, the following works (similar to one of your attempts):

```
$ printf 'one::two\nthree:::four\n' | sed 's/:\{2,3\}/_/'
one_two
three_four
```

Of course, all this is simplified if you use Extended RE instead of sed's default Basic RE notation.  (You can `man re_format` for more information about this.)

In Linux and FreeBSD, this works:

```
$ printf 'one::two\nthree:::four\n' | sed -r 's/:::?/_/'
one_two
three_four
```

And in FreeBSD and OSX, this works:

```
$ printf 'one::two\nthree:::four\n' | sed -E 's/:::?/_/'
one_two
three_four
```

Yes, FreeBSD supports both `-r` and `-E` for Extended RE.  The `-E` option was introduced years ago, and OSX used the BSD source code for their own version.  Later versions of FreeBSD have added `-r` for compatibility with GNU sed, but OSX hasn't adopted that version yet.

Of course, I should point out that all of these suffer in that they are not anchored to non-colon characters on either side.  So technically, if you search for just `::`, you will also match `:::`:

```
printf 'one::two\nthree:::four\n' | sed -r 's/::/_/'
one_two
three_:four
```

So you'd need some way to identify a "not colon" character.  You can't use word delimiters (`[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]`) because this is not a word boundary, but this should work:

```
$ printf 'one::two\nthree:::four\nfive::::six\n' | sed -r 's/([^:])(:::?)([^:])/\1_\3/'
one_two
three_four
five::::six
```

Even in BRE:

```
printf 'one::two\nthree:::four\nfive::::six\n' | sed 's/\([^:]\):\{2,3\}\([^:]\)/\1_\2/'
one_two
three_four
five::::six
```

Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following expression if you want to match any number of colons here

```
s/(:)+/*/g
```

This will replace any number of colons to `*`

Your output will be

```
TestEko* Test
TestEko* Test
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/:::\?/X&X/' file # should print TestEkoX:::XTest and TestEkoX::XTest
```